# GCP DataFlow unable to import package mentioned in setup.py

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to import **lxml** package in my python apache beam code running in GCP Dataflow, for that as we need additional dependencies like  "libxml2-dev", "libxslt-dev", those are mentioned in **setup.py** file.

My **setup.py file** will look like,

```
import subprocess

import setuptools
from setuptools.command.bdist_egg import bdist_egg as _bdist_egg


class bdist_egg(_bdist_egg):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
  """A bdist_egg command class that will be invoked during package install.
  The package built using the current setup.py will be staged and later
  installed in the worker using `easy_install package'. This class will be
  instantiated during install for this specific scenario and will trigger
  running the custom commands specified.
  """

  def run(self):
    self.run_command('CustomCommands')
    _bdist_egg.run(self)


# Some custom command to run during setup. The command is not essential for this
# workflow. It is used here as an example. Each command will spawn a child
# process. Typically, these commands will include steps to install non-Python
# packages. For instance, to install a C++-based library libjpeg62 the following
# two commands will have to be added:
#
#     ['apt-get', 'update'],
#     ['apt-get', '--assume-yes', install', 'libjpeg62'],
#
# First, note that there is no need to use the sudo command because the setup
# script runs with appropriate access.
# Second, if apt-get tool is used then the first command needs to be 'apt-get
# update' so the tool refreshes itself and initializes links to download
# repositories.  Without this initial step the other apt-get install commands
# will fail with package not found errors. Note also --assume-yes option which
# shortcuts the interactive confirmation.
#
# The output of custom commands (including failures) will be logged in the
# worker-startup log.
CUSTOM_COMMANDS = [
    ['sudo', 'apt-get', 'update'],
    ['sudo', 'apt-get', '--assume-yes', 'install', 'python-dev'],
    ['sudo', 'apt-get', '--assume-yes', 'install', 'libxml2-dev'],
    ['sudo', 'apt-get', '--assume-yes', 'install', 'libxslt1-dev'],
    ]


class CustomCommands(setuptools.Command):
  """A setuptools Command class able to run arbitrary commands."""

  def initialize_options(self):
    pass

  def finalize_options(self):
    pass

  def RunCustomCommand(self, command_list):
    print 'Running command: %s' % command_list
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        command_list,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    # Can use communicate(input='y\n'.encode()) if the command run requires
    # some confirmation.
    stdout_data, _ = p.communicate()
    print 'Command output: %s' % stdout_data
    if p.returncode != 0:
      raise RuntimeError(
          'Command %s failed: exit code: %s' % (command_list, p.returncode))

  def run(self):
    for command in CUSTOM_COMMANDS:
      self.RunCustomCommand(command)


# Configure the required packages and scripts to install.
# Note that the Python Dataflow containers come with numpy already installed
# so this dependency will not trigger anything to be installed unless a version
# restriction is specified.
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ["gcsfs", "google-cloud-storage==1.44.0", "lxml"]


setuptools.setup(
    name='packagesinstall',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='workflow package.',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    cmdclass={
         #Command class instantiated and run during easy_install scenarios.
        'bdist_egg': bdist_egg,
        'CustomCommands': CustomCommands,
        }
    )
```

The following command is ran.

```
python  -m xmltojson --region us-west4  --runner DataflowRunner     --project gcp-bq-2021     --temp_location gs://gcp-bq-2021/tmp/  **--setup_file ./setup.py**
```

**The Dataflow run still fails with "NO MODULE NAMED LXML"**
[image: error_message]

Is there anything wrong in the setup.py file or the process which I am doing to install the package. Kindly assist me.

Comment: There is no much sense on the command `python  -m xmltojson --region us-west4 ...`  Is it right ? you should be running your pipeline instead of calling the xmltojson module. Also, all the options (region, runner,...) are being ignored, since they just work when sent to the apache beam library. Please clarify what and how you are running your pipeline please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that lxml depends on non-python dependencies you installed. So you have to put the PyPI package installation as a CUSTOM_COMMANDS `['pip', 'install', 'lxml']` instead of as a REQUIRED_PACKAGES. Details see: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#nonpython.